# RoR: how can I get a micropost to be created by two seperate micropost forms according to an element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My microposts have a column called type which is a string. This can either be purchase or sale. I want two seperate input forms, where if you input content into one then it automatically fills in purchase as the type (when creating the micropost) and if you input content into the other it automatically fills in sale. .

Here is my form as it is

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I recently added type as a column in the micropost data table. That is why there is no input for it (yet). Read above for how I want the type to be automatically filled in

Im thinking one way to do it is to id each form with something. Then when the form is being filled in, I could somehow tell it to automatically fill in the hidden type field based on which form is filled in. IS this possible??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the `hidden_field` here.  Use `hidden_field` to pass information to the controller without presenting it to the user.  Here is one form for the purchase:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :type, 'purchase' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and another for the sale:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to sell?" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :type, 'sale' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```